# A propriedade ou o indexador "Color.Name" não pode ser atribuído, pois é somente leitura

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propriedade

Segue código onde defino `SegundaTela`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SegundaTela telaSecundaria;
}
```

Código:

```
telaSecundaria = new SegundaTela();
telaSecundaria.label_segunda_tela.BackColor.Name = cor_fundo;
```

Recebo erro:

> CS0200    A propriedade ou o indexador "Color.Name" não pode ser
>   atribuído, pois é somente leitura

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro é auto descritivo, não pode mudar o nome da cor. Por que quer mudar o nome dela? Isto não faz sentido.

Se quer mudar a cor, apenas mude a cor, não mude o nome dela. A solução é não fazer isto.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.name?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Color_Name).

Então pode fazer:

```
telaSecundaria.label_segunda_tela.BackColor = cor_fundo;
```

Estou partindo do princípio que `cor_fundo` é um uma variável do tipo [`Color`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Se não for isto daria erro porque a propriedade [`BackColor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_BackColor) espera isto. Se for uma *string* com o nome pode usar o [`FromName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromname?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Color_FromName_System_String_) (obviamente precisa ser uma das *strings* registradas no *framework* para funcionar. Então faria algo assim:

```
var cor_fundo = Color.FromName("Blue");
```

Exemplo:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Drawing;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Color slateBlue = Color.FromName("SlateBlue");
        WriteLine($"Slate Blue has these ARGB values: Alpha:{slateBlue.A}, red:{slateBlue.R}, green: {slateBlue.B}, blue {slateBlue.G}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0Yibnq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q9zU8g). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ChangeColor.cs).

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer mudar a cor do `label`. A propriedade que você precisa trabalhar é a `ForeColor` e se você quer alterar a cor de fundo, não é atribuindo o `Name` que conseguirá, basta atribuir o valor do struct [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) a propriedade `BackColor`:

Veja como ficaria:

```
telaSecundaria = new SegundaTela();
telaSecundaria.label_segunda_tela.BackColor = Color.Red;
telaSecundaria.label_segunda_tela.ForeColor = Color.White;
```